Must I file 1040-NR in my case?
I'm in the EU, in a country with a tax treaty with the US. I'm not a US citizen.
I won 2000 USD from a MTG online tournament. 30% went to withholding tax. I don't have any other US income during the same calendar year. The US company hosting the online tournament asked me to fill in a W8BEN form. Now I've received a 1042-S form.
My question is now, is it legally mandatory for me to file a 1040-NR? Or is it optional for me to do so?
Thanks for help.


My question is now, is it legally mandatory for me to file a 1040-NR? Or is it optional for me to do so?

It is not mandatory, but if you want to claim any treaty benefits or receive a refund because the actual tax rate should have been less than 30% - you should file. You might need to file if you want to claim tax credit in your home country - check with the local tax authorities if they require it.

It is optional. However, you will lose treaty benefit if any, and filing will get you the refund.
To avoid filing for refund in the future and let the platform withholds the correct amount of taxes, do not skip the tax treaty section in W8BEN.
